# ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("TBLS"."FTP_GET_TESTING"."FTP_LOOKUP_ID"), but as far as I can tell it is not null

Tags: entity-framework-6, oracle12c

I can't figure out what the problem is. I am using Entity Framework 6 to access an Oracle 12c Database. When I try to add a new row to the table I get the ORA-01400 error in my title. However, when I look at the values that I am attempting to add in the debugger they are not null.

```
 protected void InsertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
     AddNewPartner(GetFields());            
}

 public void AddNewPartner(FTP_GET_TESTING ftpPartner)
{               
    using (Entities myEntities = new Entities())
    {
            myEntities.FTP_GET_TESTING.Add(ftpPartner);
            myEntities.SaveChanges();            
    }
}
```

**Update**

Here is the model(it is Data First):

```
public partial class FTP_GET_TESTING
{
public string FTP_LOOKUP_ID { get; set; }
public string FTP_HOST { get; set; }
public string USER_NAME { get; set; }
public string PASSWORD { get; set; }
public string ADAPTER { get; set; }
public string FTP_MODE { get; set; }
public string PICKUP_FOLDER { get; set; }
public string DESTINATION_FOLDER { get; set; }
public string DELIVERY_FILENAME { get; set; }
public string DESTINATION_BP { get; set; }
public string ARCHIVE_FOLDER { get; set; }
public string REMOTE_ARCHIVE_FILE_EXTENSION { get; set; }
public string REMOTE_ARCHIVE_DIRECTORY { get; set; }
public string REMOTE_FILE_DELETE { get; set; }
public string FTP_DOWN { get; set; }
public string FILTER { get; set; }
public string LISTSIZE_FLAG { get; set; }
public decimal LIST_MAX { get; set; }
public string CHECK_FILE_SIZE { get; set; }
public string PGP_DECRYPT { get; set; }
public string PGP_PASSPHRASE { get; set; }
public string CONNECTION_TYPE { get; set; }
public string REPRESENTATION_TYPE { get; set; }
public string FTPS_CACERTIFICATE_ID { get; set; }
public string FTPS_CIPHER_STRENGTH { get; set; }
public string PORT { get; set; }
public string FTPS_SSL { get; set; }
public string FTPS_SYSTEM_CERT_ID { get; set; }
public string SFTP_COMPRESSION { get; set; }
public string SFTP_KNOWNHOST_KEY_ID { get; set; }
public string SFTP_PREF_AUTH_METHOD { get; set; }
public string SFTP_PREFERRED_CIPHER { get; set; }
public string SFTP_PREFERRED_MAC { get; set; }
public string SFTP_USER_ID_KEY_ID { get; set; }
public string FMC_RELATIONSHIP_NAME { get; set; }
public string USER_FIELD1 { get; set; }
public string USER_FIELD2 { get; set; }
public string USER_FIELD3 { get; set; }
public string NOTES { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> LAST_UPDATE { get; set; }
public string LAST_USER_UPDATE { get; set; }
public string PARTNER_NAME { get; set; }
public string MAILBOX_ID { get; set; }
public string REMEDY_QUEUE { get; set; }
public string SCHEDULE { get; set; }
public Nullable<decimal> ALERT_FREQUENCY { get; set; }
public string PRIORITY { get; set; }
public string CONTACT_NAME { get; set; }
public string CONTACT_EMAIL { get; set; }
public string CONTACT_PHONE { get; set; }
public string FTP_SEND_LOOKUP_ID { get; set; }
}
```

I verify the data added using the immediate window in the debugger.

```
myEntities.FTP_GET_TESTING.Add(ftpGet);
   {GP_GENERIC_FTP_GET_TESTING}
   ADAPTER: "FTP_Client_Adapter_Group"
   ALERT_FREQUENCY: 120
   ARCHIVE_FOLDER: ""
   CHECK_FILE_SIZE: "NO"
   CONNECTION_TYPE: "PASSIVE"
   CONTACT_EMAIL: "Atest"
   CONTACT_NAME: "Atest"
   CONTACT_PHONE: "Atest"
   DELIVERY_FILENAME: ""
   DESTINATION_BP: ""
   DESTINATION_FOLDER: ""
   FILTER: ""
   FMC_RELATIONSHIP_NAME: ""
   FTPS_CACERTIFICATE_ID: ""
   FTPS_CIPHER_STRENGTH: ""
   FTPS_SSL: ""
   FTPS_SYSTEM_CERT_ID: ""
   FTP_DOWN: "N"
   FTP_HOST: "Change"
   FTP_LOOKUP_ID: "AnotherTest4"
   FTP_MODE: "FTP"
   FTP_SEND_LOOKUP_ID: ""
   LAST_UPDATE: {12/28/2015 8:49:49 AM}
   LAST_USER_UPDATE: "driver"
   LISTSIZE_FLAG: "TRUE"
   LIST_MAX: 520
   MAILBOX_ID: ""
   NOTES: "Atest"
   PARTNER_NAME: "Atest"
   PASSWORD: "Atest"
   PGP_DECRYPT: "N"
   PGP_PASSPHRASE: ""
   PICKUP_FOLDER: ""
   PORT: "21"
   PRIORITY: "8x5"
   REMEDY_QUEUE: "Atest"
   REMOTE_ARCHIVE_DIRECTORY: ""
   REMOTE_ARCHIVE_FILE_EXTENSION: ""
   REMOTE_FILE_DELETE: "Y"
   REPRESENTATION_TYPE: "BINARY"
   SCHEDULE: "60MIN"
   SFTP_COMPRESSION: ""
   SFTP_KNOWNHOST_KEY_ID: ""
   SFTP_PREFERRED_CIPHER: "blowfish-cbc"
   SFTP_PREFERRED_MAC: ""
   SFTP_PREF_AUTH_METHOD: ""
   SFTP_USER_ID_KEY_ID: ""
   USER_FIELD1: ""
   USER_FIELD2: ""
   USER_FIELD3: ""
   USER_NAME: "Atest"
```

and I think this is the config info you wanted to see.

```
<configSections>
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
<section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
```

What else do I need to add here to help figure out the problem?

Comment: Turn on logging and look at the exact query/parameters - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx

Comment: I am sorry but I can't imagine how we supposed to figure out what is wrong from 6 lines of code.

Comment: @Gergely Bacso Hence the question "What else do I need to add here...". I was not sure what specifically would be needed so I provided a basic outline.

Comment: Model first; the code where you build the instance that supposed to have the ID set to something; the way you proved to yourself that the ID in question is actually populated; any config related to the database persisting part of your app.

Comment: In Oracle an empty string `""` (or `''` in SQL syntax) is considered `NULL`

Comment: Right, but even if I fill in all fields(including the ones that allow null) I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I did two things. First I deleted the model FTP_GET_TESTING and then I compared the primary key(FTP_LOOKUP_ID) in the testing table to the PK in the non testing table and there were some differences.
In design view of the table FTP_GET_TESTING my PK Constraint was named SYS_C0027857 I changed it to FTP_GET_TESTING_PK. I also changed the name of the index to match the constraint name FTP_GET_TESTING_PK. Then I added the table back into my model and it worked perfectly.

I am not sure if changing the PK name in constraints and indexes fixed the issue or if simply deleting and re-adding did the trick.

If anyone cares to add some input on this for future viewers, and so that I can understand what happened a little more I would appreciate it.